# Getting error when loading users data from git api

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, github

I am working on a basic git users search box on my page here I am getting this error. 403 (Forbidden)" Here is my javascript code I am using. Can anyone help me.

```
function showHint(str) {
  var xhttp;
  if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       users = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = users.items[0].login
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/search/users?q="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();   
}
```

Comment: It is working for me.

Comment: Hello amardeep. Did you tried in online editor or did you saved code in your desktop and exectued..?

Comment: Because it is working for me when I run in w3 school editor but not when I run save it in a file run it not working.?

Comment: I saved it as a .html file in my desktop and tried, still worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saved this file locally and invoked the `showHint()` function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str) {
  var xhttp;
  if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       users = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = users.items[0].login
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/search/users?q="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();   
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="showHint('amardeep')">Click me</button>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Amardeep I started debugging then I came to know that, when I am printing readystate I am getting undefined in my console. So I took of that part then It started working.